# CSV File Into MYSQL Merging - LOAD DATA on Duplicate Key?

Tags: mysql, import, csv, bulk

Hey Dba Stack Exchange,

My question to you is with regards to mysql. Right now I have a medium to small sized csv with 25k lines I need imported into mysql for a client. Problem is, their is only 4411 unique key rows. Rest have the same primary key and thus are skipped. I cant replace into because all the columns are present in the csv. I need to do (in mongodb terms Upsert).

Basically my question is what is the best method to update the existing columns like a ON DUPLICATE KEY during an insert for bulk csv file loading.

Database is Mysql

```
Table1 {

userID VARCHAR(50) PK,

UnixTimestamp VARCHAR(100),

likesCars TINYINT(1),

likesTrucks TINYINT(1),

HasMorgage TINYINT(1),

... 1000 more

}
```

Data:

```
2323232,1111111,1,0,0,0,1...

2323232,2333222,0,0,0,1,0... (needs merge)

1121121,222222,0,1,1,0,0...
```

goes on and on haha.

Was thinking maybe since they are mainly tiny ints changing

```
Load Data InFile CSv... (userId, @unixTimestamp, @likesCars, @likesTrucks...)

SET unixTimestamp = @unixTimestamp

SET likesCars = @LikesCars OR LikesCars

SET likesTrucks = @LikesTrucks OR LikesTrucks
```

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: Please show the table structure of the table you want to load. Please also show a sample of row/columns that will be inserted into the table.

Comment: Hopefully this helps

Comment: Question to help me understand: Are you saying the merge of the first lines should look like this: `2323232,2333222,1,0,0,1,1...` ?

Comment: Another Question: Does Table1 already have data in it ?

Comment: Table 1 is empty,

The first column is the ID, the second is the timestamp. The timestamp can just get replaced with the one farther down (lower in the file the later the timestamp would be generated). Also the above merge you posted would be correct.